# Dynamically create a HTML5 video element without it being shown in the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, html5-video

Is it possible to dynamically create a HTML5 video element so that I can access the element by API's like `document.getElementById` or Name but it may not show up in the webpage.

Something like `div.hide()` or something in that direction ?

Comment: If you've created the element, why do you need to try to fetch a reference to it from the document? Just keep the reference you get when you create it.

Comment: sure. That's possible. Google a bit and you'll find an answer.

Comment: use css to hide it by `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` or if use jquery's `hide()` method. Then show it as per your needs.

Comment: The best way would be which I implemented as well to embed the video and remove it within a single execution.Thus we get to manuipulate the dom and it doesn't show up as well in web page.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can try

```
var video = document.createElement('video');

video.src = 'urlToVideo.ogg';
video.autoplay = true;
```

you can also use the `canPlayType` method to check if the browser supports the video format you want to use before setting source

```
if (video.canPlayType('video/ogg').length > 0) {
    /* set some video source */
}
```

The method returns `maybe` or `perhaps` depending on browser. If empty string it means it can't play it.

You can now use the `video` using the API. Just store it globally. You can later insert it into the DOM. Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to dynamically create a video element and append it to a specific DIV, when I drag/drop a file onto the web page. In the example code, `urlToVideo.ogg` is a server side relative url, presumably. All I have with me is the local URL, from the file.

Comment: use video.autoplay = true not autoPlay

Comment: note, if you add this to the document, it will reload the src from the network.

Answer (score 28):

Sure you can create everything just using JS. You need nothing to be pre-created in html body.

Here is simple way of creating video element in JS:

```
var videlem = document.createElement("video");
/// ... some setup like poster image, size, position etc. goes here...
/// now, add sources:
var sourceMP4 = document.createElement("source"); 
sourceMP4.type = "video/mp4";
sourceMP4.src = "path-to-video-file.mp4";
videlem.appendChild(sourceMP4);
//// same approach add ogg/ogv and webm sources
```

Before doing this, you should check if browser supports video element, and if so, which file formats can be played. This you can do by:

```
var supportsVideoElement = !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
```

Then, if video element is supported, test which video formats can be played:

```
var temp = document.createElement('video');
var canPlay_MP4 = temp.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"');
var canPlay_OGV = temp.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora,vorbis"');
var canPlay_WEMB = temp.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8,vorbis"');
```

After this, you can add video element to your page using JS only, with proper video sources set. There may be an issue with .htaccess on server side where you need to add lines:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

This may not be needed, depending on how your server is set, but if you encounter issue with playing videos from your server, but they play fine from eg. localhost on your dev machine, this can solve the issue. .htaccess with above lines should be placed in the folder where video files are located, on server side.

Ok now, in order to have this element available with getElementById(...), you just need to set id of it, when you create it:

```
var videlem = document.createElement("video");
videlem.id = "xxxxxx";
```

And now you can later find it using:

```
var videlem = document.getElementById("xxxxxx");
```

However, as someone commented already, you don't need to do this if you have already created the element and have variable pointing to it... just use it directly.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I know we can create all kinds of elements like video/iframe but I think we have to remove the element during the same cycle so that it doesn't show up in the DOM.So we have to removeElement as well after creating one else it will show up in the DOM.

Comment: Any particular reason why you create a temp video object and don't call canPlayType on the videlem you are going to use in the DOM?

Comment: @Micros the snippet you refer to is if you just want to test what formats can be played, so later when you create videos, you don't need to put all sources, just one that can be played. It can also help you to determine if there is support for video tag, but for some reason, available codecs are not going to play. In my opinion, testing should be done only once (eg. on document load), and not every time you add video to document.

Comment: you shouldn't add the src in js, if you add this to the document, it will reload the src from the network again

Comment: @Nikos I am not aware of such behavior. So how would you add src otherwise if video element is dynamically created?

Answer (score 5):

Updated (and simplest) way to achieve this (since Google searches are leading here):

```
var x = document.createElement("VIDEO");

if (x.canPlayType("video/mp4")) {
    x.setAttribute("src","movie.mp4");
} else {
    x.setAttribute("src","movie.ogg");
}

x.setAttribute("width", "320");
x.setAttribute("height", "240");
x.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: note, if you add this to the document, it will reload the src from the network.