# Rendering six video textures on a cube using three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures

I have a video that looks as follows:

[Screenshot of the input video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ6ON.jpg)

As you can probably make out from the screenshot of the video, I have divided a video of a stream into 6 parts.

**Aim**: I want to project these 6 videos, on the six faces of a cube. To do that I have written the following JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebGL/Three.js Step Tutorial</title>
        <style>
            body {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three-tut.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


    <script>


     var camera;
     var scene;
     var renderer;
     var mesh;


     init();
     animate();

     function init() {

         scene = new THREE.Scene();
         camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

         var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
         light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
         scene.add(light);

         var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);


        var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( 'videos/Input.mp4' );
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

         var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture } );

         var face1 = [new THREE.Vector2(0, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, 1), new THREE.Vector2(0, 1)];
         var face2 = [new THREE.Vector2(.3333, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, 1), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, 1)];
         var face3 = [new THREE.Vector2(.6666, .5), new THREE.Vector2(1, .5), new THREE.Vector2(1, 1), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, 1)];
         var face4 = [new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, 0), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, .5), new THREE.Vector2(0, .5)];
         var face5 = [new THREE.Vector2(.3333, 0), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, 0), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.3333, .5)];
         var face6 = [new THREE.Vector2(.6666, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, 0), new THREE.Vector2(1, .5), new THREE.Vector2(.6666, .5)];

         geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [ face1[0], face1[1], face1[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [ face1[1], face1[2], face1[3] ];

             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][2] = [ face2[0], face2[1], face2[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][3] = [ face2[1], face2[2], face2[3] ];

             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][4] = [ face3[0], face3[1], face3[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][5] = [ face3[1], face3[2], face3[3] ];

             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][6] = [ face4[0], face4[1], face4[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][7] = [ face4[1], face4[2], face4[3] ];

            geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][8] = [ face5[0], face5[1], face5[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][9] = [ face5[1], face5[2], face5[3] ];

             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][10] = [ face6[0], face6[1], face6[3] ];
             geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][11] = [ face6[1], face6[2], face6[3] ];

         mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,  material);
         mesh.position.z = -50;
         scene.add( mesh );

         renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
         renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
         document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

         window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

         render();
     }

     function animate() {
         mesh.rotation.x += .04;
         mesh.rotation.y += .02;

         render();
         requestAnimationFrame( animate );
     }

     function render() {
         renderer.render( scene, camera );
     }


     function onWindowResize() {
         camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
         camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
         renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
         render();
     }

</script>
```

As you can see, I have used UV mapping to map the six different parts of the video onto the six faces of the cube.

The three-tut.js file (which is referred to in the above code) is this:

```
 var camera;
 var scene;
 var renderer;
 var mesh;

 init();
 animate();

 function init() {

     scene = new THREE.Scene();
     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

     var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
     light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
     scene.add(light);

     var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
     var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );

     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );
     mesh.position.z = -50;
     scene.add( mesh );

     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
     document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

     window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

     render();
 }

 function animate() {
     mesh.rotation.x += .03;
     mesh.rotation.y += .03;

     render();
     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 }

 function render() {
     renderer.render( scene, camera );
 }


 function onWindowResize() {
     camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
     renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
     render();
 }
```

The entire thing is not working. This is what my web-page (in chrome) looks like:

[The output on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neJqQ.png)
There are no errors in the 'Console' tab.

Please let me know where am I going wrong. 
I am just a beginning with three.js and any sort of help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Here's my demo](http://bl.ocks.org/user01/65cbe8f15fe6f338f709dbc1b311575f).

Essentially, I checked out [mrdoob's](https://github.com/mrdoob) example on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_video.html) and stole until things worked.

The main change was having a `display:none` html video element to play the actual video (without diving into the three.js code, I assume passing a url is supposed to do that on the fly, or something to that effect. [You could do that too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251983/dynamically-create-a-html5-video-element-without-it-being-shown-in-the-page), if you need everything in the js code.)

```
<video id="video" autoplay loop style="display:none">
  <source src="sintel.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Which is then referenced in the js code:

```
video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
```

Ambitious how you hand code the UVs on the cube, but it does work. You may want to look into importing a mesh with UV coordinates to make your code more flexible.

Posting the code was good, but I know posting a working demo, either a bl.ock or a jsfiddle or your own server, would be quite helpful in the future.

I'm more stumped by the purpose of three-tut.js. As far as I can tell, that does zlich. Or rather, it defines a scene with a cube, shoves a three.js renderer onto the body, and then proceeds to do nothing, except mess with your video cube mesh (that renderAnimationFrame() call ends up refering to the same `mesh` and so double hammers the rotation code.) The whole thing does not help you with the video cube.

Comment: Did you crop the sintel.mp4 video? Or did it happen somehow?

Comment: I did nothing to the mp4, just used the demo file as is, so that could be the source of UV stretching (ie, doesn't match your aspect ratio). You can check it out on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/user01/65cbe8f15fe6f338f709dbc1b311575f) if you want to inspect it for codec, resolutions, or the like.

Comment: Thanks! How do I deal with this? 

WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video
[.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Are you sure the video is being loaded into the element? Can you post a demo of your current state?