# How to using three.js show a video file in 3D scene?

Tags: three.js

Wanna achieve result something like this:

[image]

I already knows how to playing FBX animation in three.js, but how to simply place a video file in 3D scene like this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the video texture here

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture.

By this, You could set the video into a texture and set this texture inside the material.

And you may want to create Video element without getElementId,
And this may help you
[Dynamically create a HTML5 video element without it being shown in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251983/dynamically-create-a-html5-video-element-without-it-being-shown-in-the-page)

Comment: You are either provide a solution, nor lead a correct way. Please don't just paste some links here. I have almost solved my question and I will update my answer later.

Comment: This is how the question has been interpreted. If you want a more accurate solution you should have a better explanation to articulate your problem.
No one going to be your mind reader.